# Django1.10 cannot save korean characters(Mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I got the error below in django when saving a field with Korean character in the admin panel.

```
OperationalError at /admin/blog/post/add/
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xEC\\xB9\\xB4\\xED\\x8E\\x98...' for 
column 'object_repr' at row 1")
```

I'm sure the database(DB, tables, column) is ready for utf8mb4, because I can write/read these korean character in phpmyadmin and django shell.
Also, I set DATABASE  section in the settings.py with

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'password',
        'HOST' : '',
        'PORT' : '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: change the charset to utf8_unicode_ci, it will work with all languages

Comment: @Exprator I tried but it did not work out. Thank you for comment.

Comment: you can once go with utf8_general_ci @jin

Comment: @Exprator utf8_general_ci did not work out too.I really stuck